# Matrix whose element $A_{m,n}$ only depend on $m - n$ or $m+n$

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am encountering a problem that would require me to look into matrices with the following form:  the elements $A_{m,n}$ only depend on $m-n$ or $m+n,$ such as:
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c\\
d&a&b\\
e&d&a\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Is there an acronym for such matrices?

[Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4414680/singular-value-decomposition-for-a-convolution-kernel)

Comment: They are called symmetric matrices.

Comment: Yes, they are symmetric, but there are additional properties like A12=A23,A11=A22=A33.

Comment: Your matrix depends on $|m-n|,$ which is stronger than $m-n.$ In particular, there are $5$ dimensions if it depends on $m-n$ and only theee if it depends on $|m-n|.$

Comment: Thanks, so I modified the example such that it depend on m-n.

Comment: Matrices that are diagonally constant are called Toeplitz matrices.

Comment: Such a property is not a property of the underlying linear function, because a change of basis will yield a matrix that does not have this property. That doesn’t mean such a designation has no purpose…

Comment: If $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=A^T,$ the. Such a matrix can be written as $aI+bA+cA^2+dB+dB^2.$ This can be written more generally in $n\times n$ matrices with a particular $A$ with $A^n=0, A^{n-1}\neq 0,$ and $B=A^T.$ Then every such matrix can be written $$a_0I+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(a_kA^k+b_kB^k\right).$$ Not sure if this clarifies anything. $AB$ and $BA$ both end up being diagonal matrices of $n-1$ ones and $1$ zero.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Hankel matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) also links to Toeplitz matrix.